# MobileFirst Authentication Realm doesn't accept testUser

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

In my application I use a mobileSecurityTest to deal with my authentication.

This works:

```
    <mobileSecurityTest name="MAPCertLogin">
    <!-- <testUser realm="MAPLoginRealm"/> -->          
        <testDirectUpdate mode="perRequest"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="custom" realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>
        <testAppAuthenticity/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

But I want an userId in my mobilefirst operations console because I want to send push notifications via the Push Sender. I tried this:

```
    <mobileSecurityTest name="MAPCertLogin">
        <testUser realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>       
        <testDirectUpdate mode="perRequest"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="custom" realm="MAPLoginRealm"/>
        <testAppAuthenticity/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

The userId is now the same as the deviceId (which doesn't matter that much) but now the loginrealm is broken. I get this error when I launch the application for the first time:

```
[WARNING ] FWLSE0239W: Authentication failure in realm 'MAPLoginRealm': login fail [project ....................]
```

Anyone has any idea how to add an userId to my device so I can send PushNotifications?

With the first piece of code I provided I get this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0qIv.png . Like I said, I need an userId to send Pushnotifications but I don't have it.

Comment: The use of the word "console" is very confusing. What do you mean in that sentence?

Comment: What I mean is the MobileFist Operations Console. the page where you can see all your devices and applications. With the first piece of code I provided I get this result: http://i.imgur.com/VbzYNzk.png . Like I said, I need an userId to send Pushnotifications but I don't have it.

Comment: Device provisioning and user realms are normally two different things. The challenge handlers also differ. Update the post with 
1) your authenticationConfig.xml  ( showing realm definitions, authenticators and login modules)
2) your challenge handler code
3) your MobileFirst version ( screenshot looks like 70 - confirm)

Comment: @Jelmer please update the question according to the request by Vivin or remove the question...